# oracle query to mysql left joins

Tags: mysql, left-join

i migrated the company oracle database to mysql (yeah don't ask me why) and few queries (for reporting) are huge and working in mysql

one of them is 4021 lines with 89 INNER JOIN

this one generates a fully details report for the company client for financial for the last year.

i need that report (since we getting to the end of the year soon) working for 2011 and i saw on many website that the max left join for mysql is 60 something left join.

am i screwed with this report? or there's a way for me to run it?

Comment: If you need new joins because your report covers a new year, your data model is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I think your report query will anyway result in `using temporary` in EXPLAIN. You can break your single query into several in a transaction and make the temporary tables explicitly.

This can be even more helpful if your Oracle query contains something like named subqueries (I mean  `WITH` subqueries from T-SQL, I do not know if they exist in Oracle, but definitely do not exist in MySQL).

Comment: CTEs exist in normal databases but mysql :))) . The space allocated for temporary tables has also a finite number even in mysql you ought to think about that too :))

Answer (score 0):

You would have to jump up (or down, depending on your view) to a programming language to get around this (Ruby, PHP, Python, etc) would all make handling that many joins easier by just using native objects instead of relying solely on a huge join.

And you are correct, the max number of joins in MySQL is 61 ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html )

Comment: The link you provided says the maximum number of tables that can be referenced in any one `JOIN` statement is 61, not that the maximum number of `JOIN`s in any one query is 61.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case, you might want to try and break the query up some and get some of the "left join" content pre-queried along with some other elements where practical.  For example, you could pre query things like (and just guessing)

Inventory items with categories with G/L account code (id columns), etc as one pre-query.

Join that with All order details to order header summary to get customer ID and join to customers as another pre-query.  Ensure whatever key elements to join to the overall report requirement.

Continue down the list where possible and you can probably kill a bunch as they would be results of SUBQueries where no one level would have 61 joins going on.

Answer (score 0):

use enums type, that will save you from painful left joins

if you have few tables you can remove by just using `enum` that is a great improvement.

specially with what kind of data you have